# How can I manage load of my projects?

Tags: pressure

I am working in a software firm where I am given the responsibility of maintaining five software code-bases. My task is to deliver clients' modification requests and fixing bugs.

I am feeling extreme pressure as I have limited time per day, but have a lot of things to be taken care of.

What should I do?

Comment: Are you using any management tools to organize/schedule/communicate about work to management and clients? Are these internal clients or external clients? Do you talk to clients directly or do you only get info second hand? Is there any kind of release schedule for major updates or is it continuous. Do you have QA dept. helping you or is testing all on you? Does your boss say that all jobs have equal priority or do the priorities vary?

Answer (score 2):

Discuss this situation with your manager, it's their responsibility to properly allocate resources (in this case, your working hours) to the tasks in the backlog.

You should come up with time estimates for every task that's on your plate and get your manager to sort the tasks by priority. If a new request comes in - estimate it and ask your manager where should the task go in the priority queue. If it's added to the top of the queue - make it clear that you'll have to stop working on your current tasks and get back to them only once you're done with more important work. Stick to your time estimates and update your manager immediately if you think a task may take longer than initially planned.

Having clear estimates and a clear priority order in the backlog will ensure there are no unreasonable expectations about your work: if the top two tasks take 4 hours each then this is exactly what you will accomplish today. Task #3 will be worked on tomorrow.